# How to add ProcessTemplate property to Azure Devops project's custom Process Configuration

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I need to add the following snippet to my project's process template:

```
<properties>
   <property name="MSPROJ" value="Classification\FieldMapping.xml" isFile="true" />
   <property name="Process Template" value="Scrum" />
</properties>
```

My current config looks something like this (Output from the witadmin exportprocessconfig command):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectProcessConfiguration>
  <BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory" pluralName="Bugs" singularName="Bug">
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
      <State type="Proposed" value="Approved" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Committed" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
    </States>
  </BugWorkItems>
  <FeedbackRequestWorkItems category="Microsoft.FeedbackRequestCategory">
    <States>
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </FeedbackRequestWorkItems>
 <other XML elements>
</ProjectProcessConfiguration>
```

I am not sure which process template was initially used to create the project, since it was done long back on TFS. Since then, we have upgraded to Azure Devops server 2019. I have tried comparing my template with standard process templates like Scrum, Agile, Basic & CMMI but it doesn't match with any of them.

I have also tried adding the snippet under the existing Properties element but getting this error on trying to import it back:

```
The following element contains an error: Properties. This element defines the properties for this team project.  The property name Process Template is invalid. Allowed property names are : ShowBugsOnBacklog, BugsBehavior, HiddenBacklogs, DuplicateWorkItemFlow, StateColors, WorkItemTypeIcons.
```

My questions are:

1. How do I add the Process Template type to the current XML?
2. Is the ProcessTemplate XML and the ProjectProcessConfiguration XML
   same thing?

Answer (score 0):

The steps to customize a process template is as below:

[image: Download an existing process template-->Co, upload the process template files, and then verify your changes.]

Check out the [document Customize a process template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/process-templates/customize-process?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) for detailed information.

**ProcessTemplate XML and the ProjectProcessConfiguration XML are different things.**

ProcessTemplate.xml is also called the the root XML file:

> To define the sequence of plug-in files to be processed and the dependencies of each plug-in. The ProcessTemplate.xml file contains all task groups that must run to successfully create a project. Each task group references a subordinate XML plug-in file (often in a subfolder) where the specific tasks are defined. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/process-templates/overview-process-template-files?view=azure-devops-2020#the-root-process-template-file) for more information.

Check Process template XML elements in document [Process template XML elements reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/process-templates/process-template-xml-elements-reference?view=azure-devops-2020).

ProjectProcessConfiguration XML:

> Process configuration defines the default configuration and functional capabilities that your teams can access using the web portal Agile tools. These tools, include the product backlog, sprint backlogs, Kanban board, and task board and are customizable for each team you add to project.

Check [Process configuration XML element reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/process-configuration-xml-element?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) for more information.